# How to remove the errors in the multi level inheritance in the following Java code?

Tags: java

I am learning the multilevel inheritance in Java and i got stuck in the following code.But it's showing 1 error.And is there any other way for doing this.Can I do the inheritance while using methods?Can anyone help?Thanks in advance.
This is the error:

shoppingmain.java:27: error: constructor B in class B cannot be applied to given types;
{
^
  required: String,int

found: no arguments

reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

1 error

```
    class A{
    int price;
    String product;
    }

    class B extends A
    {
     int quantity; 
     int total;
    B(String a,int b)
    {

    product=a;
    price=b;
    }
    void productdetails()
    {
     System.out.println("The product name is"+product);
     System.out.println("The price is"+price);
    }
    }

    class C extends B
    {
    C(int c,int d)
    {          //line 27
    quantity=c;
    total=d;
    }
    void productcost()
    {
    System.out.println("The quantity is"+quantity);
    System.out.println("The total cost is"+total);
    }
    }

    class shoppingmain
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

    B obj1=new B("pen",5);
    C obj2=new C(2,10);

    obj1.productdetails();
    obj2.productcost();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please: a) reduce this to a [mcve]; b) format the code - it's all over the place at the moment; c) include the error within the question, rather than just saying "it's showing errors"; d) follow Java naming conventions to make the example as easy to read as possible; e) say what you're trying to achieve... you ask "is there any other way for doing this" without saying what "this" is.

Comment: After You made like @JonSkeet say, B extend A is probably bad designed (repeating variables is misunderstanding), and printing methods are bad design too

Comment: In addition to what @JonSkeet pointed out, please also indent the code properly; it's *very* challenging to read "as is."

Comment: Please also show which line is line 27.

Answer (score 0):

As you have declared a constructor in father's class, and inheritance works creating each objects from the father to the child, you neeed to specify the parameters to create B object, using **super** keyword in C:

```
public class C extends B
{
    C(int c, int d)
    {
        super("Prueba", 1);
        quantity = c;
        total = d;
    }

    void productcost()
    {
        System.out.println("The quantity is" + quantity);
        System.out.println("The total cost is" + total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you are trying to do:

```
package javaapplication20;

public class JavaApplication20 {

    public static void main(String[] args)                
    {  
        B obj1 = new B("pen",5);
        C obj2 = new C(2,10); 
        obj1.productdetails();
        obj2.productcost();        
    }
}

class A{
    int price;
    String product;
}

class B extends A
{
    int quantity; 
    int total;

    B () {

    }

    B(int q, int t) {
        quantity = q;
        total = t;
    }

    B(String a,int b)
    {
        product=a;
        price=b;
    }

    void productdetails()
    {
     System.out.println("The product name is "+product);
     System.out.println("The price is "+price);
    }
}

class C extends B
{
    C(int h,int j) {
        quantity = h;
        total = j;
    }
    void productcost()
    {
        System.out.println("The quantity is "+quantity);
        System.out.println("The total cost is "+total);
    }
}
```

Comment: EDITED: This is closer to what  you started with.